# Correct way to update a state array in a Flux Store

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have a Flux Store and a state array that needs updating when a new comment is created so that a list of comments updates in the view. I just want to confirm that I am updating it correctly using push:

```
this.state.comments.push(commentArray);
```

It works fine but I have read about immutability but as this is a store and not a view I take it this is ok?

```
 onDispatcherAction: function (payload) {

    var action = payload.action;
    if (ActionTypes.CREATE_CONFIGURATION_SETTINGS_RESPONSE === action.type) {
        this.handleResponseErrors(action.data);

        var commentArray = {
            _id: action.data._id,
            user: {
                id: action.data.user.id
            },
            id:action.data.id,
            commentname: action.data.commentname,
            timeCreated: action.data.timeCreated
        }
        this.state.commentname = action.data.commentname;

        this.state.comments.push(commentArray);

        this.emitChange();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should take a look to the [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

From [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

#### Simple push

```
var initialArray = [1, 2, 3];
var newArray = update(initialArray, {$push: [4]}); // => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`initialArray is still [1, 2, 3].`

Comment: Just adding onto this, if the desired end result is to update the state, a `this.setState({array: newArray});` call should be explicitly made afterwards.